# Parsing keyword next to special character (pyparsing)

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, text-parsing, pyparsing

Using pyparsing, how can I match a keyword immediately before or after a special character (like "{" or "}")? The code below shows that my keyword "msg" is not matched unless it is preceded by whitespace (or at start):

```
import pyparsing as pp

openBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Keyword("{"))
closeBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Keyword("}"))
messageKw = pp.Keyword("msg")
messageExpr = pp.Forward()
messageExpr << messageKw + openBrace +\
                pp.ZeroOrMore(messageExpr) + closeBrace

try:
    result = messageExpr.parseString("msg { msg { } }")
    print result.dump(), "\n"
    result = messageExpr.parseString("msg {msg { } }")
    print result.dump()
except pp.ParseException as pe:
    print pe, "\n", "Text: ", pe.line
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I have been unable to find it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
openBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Keyword("{"))
closeBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Keyword("}"))
```

should be:

```
openBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Literal("{"))
closeBrace = pp.Suppress(pp.Literal("}"))
```

or even just:

```
openBrace = pp.Suppress("{")
closeBrace = pp.Suppress("}")
```

(Most pyparsing classes will auto-promote a string argument `"arg"` to `Literal("arg")`.)

When I have parsers with many punctuation marks, rather than have a big ugly chunk of statements like this, I'll collapse them down to something like:

```
OBRACE, CBRACE, OPAR, CPAR, SEMI, COMMA = map(pp.Suppress, "{}();,")
```

The problem you are seeing is that `Keyword` looks at the immediately-surrounding characters, to make sure that the current string is not being accidentally matched when it is really embedded in a larger identifier-like string. In `Keyword('{')`, this will only work if there is no adjoining character that could be confused as part of a larger word. Since '{' itself is not really a typical keyword character, using `Keyword('{')` is not a good use of that class.

Only use `Keyword` for strings that could be misinterpreted as identifiers. For matching characters that are not in the set of typical keyword characters (by "keyword characters" I mean alphanumerics + '_'), use `Literal`.

Comment: Thank you again. It was so simple!